# How to change the default config for MySQL when using docker image?

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a MySQL server running inside of a docker container on an Ubuntu VPS using [MySQL:8.0.21 image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

I am using the following `docker-compose.yml` to bring up the server

```
version: "3"
services:
    mysql_server:
        image: mysql:8.0.21
        restart: always
        container_name: mysql_server
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: my_database
            MYSQL_USER: my_user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: my_pass
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_pass
        volumes:
            - mysql_server_data:/var/lib/mysql
            - /mysql/files:/etc/mysql/conf.d
```

But, I need a way to set the default configuration for MySQL instead of using the default config.

I tried adding the 'command`line to the`docker-compose.yml` file as you can see below. But that did not work.

```
version: "3"
services:
    mysql_server:
        image: mysql:8.0.21
        restart: always
        container_name: mysql_server
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: my_database
            MYSQL_USER: my_user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: my_pass
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_pass
        command: mysqld --innodb-buffer-pool-size=2.5G --innodb-log-file-size=512M
        volumes:
            - mysql_server_data:/var/lib/mysql
            - /mysql/files:/etc/mysql/conf.d
```

I also tried adding a file called `conf.d` in `/mysql/files` and added the following lines to it and that did not work either

```
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2.5G
```

How can I correctly change the default configuration of the MySQL instance that is running in a docker container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CMD` is already set to `mysqld` in the container, so your `command` field in your `docker-compose` file can only contain the arguments that you want to change. That is what is recommended in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html#docker-configuring-server) for the image.

For example:

```
services:
    mysql_server:
        image: mysql:8.0.21
        restart: always
        container_name: mysql_server
        [..]
        command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci --innodb-buffer-pool-size=200M
        [..]
```

Also, I am not sure if `2.5G` is a valid value for `innodb-buffer-pool-size`, so I would recommend to use integer values such as `2500M` or similar.

Comment: That did work. How can I use the custom file to save the configuration?

Comment: Mounting the config file to `/etc/my.cnf` using `volumes: - /mysql/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf` is [the documented way to use a config file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html#docker-persisting-data-configuration)